# How to set selection colour of listview programmatically

Tags: android

In `xml` file of `ListView` I have used `android:listSelector="#333333"` to set colour for *on select list item*, and this is working fine. But I want to set this colour programmatically. So please tell how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourListView.setSelector(R.color.colorname);
```

**colors.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
         <color name="colorname">#333333</color>
//other colors
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

in ListView :

```
 android:listSelector="@drawable/item"
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try

```
listVIew.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.id.color));
    }
});
```